# fatal error: 'stdarg.h' file not found

Tags: c++, osx-mountain-lion

Well I just downloaded source code and I'm sure it is correct. But after I use make command to  make file. Errors come out: My laptop is Mac-air

> `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/cstdarg:50:10: fatal error: 'stdarg.h' file not found`

Can anybody help me with this problem??

Thanks

Comment: Have you stdarg.h in your system ?

Comment: Try a one-line C++ source file: `#include <cstdarg>`; do you get the same error? If so, your compiler installation is messed up somehow.

Comment: Yes Keith same error. What can I do to tackle it?

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be a known issue - http://code.google.com/p/include-what-you-use/issues/detail?id=100

Try updating

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem after upgrading Ubuntu.  Still had clang 3.2 installed.  Explicitly upgraded to clang 3.5 and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this solved it for me.

Just install command line tools

```
xcode-select --install
```

Then set the path for the active developer directory

```
xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/
```

(you can check which directory is set with `xcode-select -p`)

---

If `xcode-select --install` says `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed` but the installation is broken, you can try:

```
rm -rf /library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: Where to do that ? in non-admin cmd with windows 10, that's my setup. I tried the solution you provided and got this: `C:\Users\R1S8k>xcode-select --install
'xcode-select' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @PerchEagle This works in macosx environment as asked above, I do not know how to resolve it on Windows, sorry.